# What to use instead of SecurityManager.IsGranted?

Tags: vb.net, permissions, user-permissions

I haven't found exactly the question I'm asking.

I want to find if the user has access/permission to delete a given file or folder

I was using this:

```
Private Function UserHasPermissionsToSource(ByVal source As String) As Boolean    
    Dim writePermission As FileIOPermission = New FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write, source)
    Return SecurityManager.IsGranted(writePermission)
End Function
```

But with the isGranted obsolete I'm not exactly sure what to replace it with. This is currently what I have, can someone confirm if this is correct or not?

```
Private Function UserHasPermissionsToSource(ByVal source As String) As Boolean
    'Get the permissions of the file/folder
    Dim writePermission As FileIOPermission = New FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write, source)

    'Create your permission set and add file permissions for write
    Dim permissionSet As PermissionSet = New PermissionSet(PermissionState.None)
    permissionSet.AddPermission(writePermission)

    'checks permissions????
    If permissionSet.IsSubsetOf(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.PermissionSet) Then
        Return True
    End If

    Return False
End Function
```

Seems like a lot more work for the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above is not correct, I found a solution.

```
Private Function GetFileAccessControl(ByVal source As String) As String

        Dim denied As Boolean = False
        Dim allowed As Boolean = False

        'Gets the current User
        Dim wid As WindowsIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()

        Try
            Dim arc As AuthorizationRuleCollection = GetAuthorizationRuleCollection(source)
            Dim ars As IList(Of FileSystemAccessRule) = New List(Of FileSystemAccessRule)(arc.OfType(Of FileSystemAccessRule))
            Dim widgs As IList(Of IdentityReference) = New List(Of IdentityReference)

            For Each g As SecurityIdentifier In wid.Groups
                If g.IsAccountSid() Then
                    widgs.Add(g)
                End If
            Next

            'User not inherited rules
            For Each rule As FileSystemAccessRule In (From r In ars Where r.IdentityReference.Equals(wid.User) AndAlso Not r.IsInherited)
                denied = denied Or DeniesWriteAccess(rule)
                allowed = allowed Or AllowsWriteAccess(rule)
            Next

            For Each rule As FileSystemAccessRule In (From r In ars Where r.IdentityReference.Equals(wid.User) AndAlso r.IsInherited)
                denied = denied Or DeniesWriteAccess(rule)
                allowed = allowed Or AllowsWriteAccess(rule)
            Next

            For Each rule As FileSystemAccessRule In (From r In ars Where widgs.Contains(r.IdentityReference) AndAlso Not r.IsInherited)
                denied = denied Or DeniesWriteAccess(rule)
                allowed = allowed Or AllowsWriteAccess(rule)
            Next

            For Each rule As FileSystemAccessRule In (From r In ars Where widgs.Contains(r.IdentityReference) AndAlso r.IsInherited)
                denied = denied Or DeniesWriteAccess(rule)
                allowed = allowed Or AllowsWriteAccess(rule)
            Next
        Catch ex As UnauthorizedAccessException

        End Try

        If Not denied AndAlso allowed Then
            Return True
        End If

        Return False
    End Function

    Private Function GetAuthorizationRuleCollection(ByVal source As String) As AuthorizationRuleCollection

        'Gets the current User
        Dim wid As WindowsIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
        Dim arc As AuthorizationRuleCollection
        arc = Nothing

        If (Directory.Exists(source)) Then
            Dim di As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(source)
            Dim acl As DirectorySecurity = di.GetAccessControl()
            arc = acl.GetAccessRules(True, True, GetType(SecurityIdentifier))
        ElseIf File.Exists(source) Then
            Dim fi As FileInfo = New FileInfo(source)
            Dim acl As FileSecurity = fi.GetAccessControl()
            arc = acl.GetAccessRules(True, True, GetType(SecurityIdentifier))
        End If

        Return arc
    End Function

    Private Function AllowsWriteAccess(rule As FileSystemAccessRule) As Boolean
        If rule.AccessControlType = AccessControlType.Allow AndAlso
                (rule.FileSystemRights.HasFlag(FileSystemRights.Write) OrElse
                rule.FileSystemRights.HasFlag(FileSystemRights.WriteData) OrElse
                rule.FileSystemRights.HasFlag(FileSystemRights.CreateDirectories) OrElse
                rule.FileSystemRights.HasFlag(FileSystemRights.CreateFiles)) Then
            Return True
        End If
        Return False
    End Function

    Private Function DeniesWriteAccess(rule As FileSystemAccessRule) As Boolean
        If rule.AccessControlType = AccessControlType.Deny AndAlso
                (rule.FileSystemRights.HasFlag(FileSystemRights.Write) OrElse
                rule.FileSystemRights.HasFlag(FileSystemRights.WriteData) OrElse
                rule.FileSystemRights.HasFlag(FileSystemRights.CreateDirectories) OrElse
                rule.FileSystemRights.HasFlag(FileSystemRights.CreateFiles)) Then
            Return True
        End If
        Return False
    End Function
```

Comment: the first function defined, `GetFileAccessControl`, should be `As Boolean`, not `As String`, seeing that it returns a boolean value.

Comment: I would also suggest naming the first function something like `HasWriteAccessForFile`, seeing that it is a check specifically for write access, not just for any permission.